# How does $x+iy = (s+it)^n \implies x-iy = (s-it)^n,$ where $x, y, s, t\in\Bbb R?$

Tags: complex-numbers

How does $x+iy = (s+it)^n \implies x-iy = (s-it)^n,$ where $x, y, s, t$ are real numbers?  (This is only a fragment of the problem I'm solving, but the only part I'm stuck on is this one.)
Why it still remains equal even after conjugating?

Thanks!

Comment: complex conjugation?

Comment: So basically $i$ can change to $-i$ everywhere, even between the parentheses to the power of $n$?

Comment: The complex conjugate of a product is the product of the complex conjugates

Comment: Alright! But how the sides of the second equation (the right one) still remain equal after conjugating?

Comment: Note:  did you mean "real" where you wrote "complex" in the title?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! Edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x-iy=\overline {x+iy}=\overline {(s+it)^n}=(\overline{s+it})^n=(s-it)^n$$

Answer (score 6):

For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}, \overline{z^n}=\overline{z}^n$. It can be proved by writing $z=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem:
$$ (s+it)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} s^{n-k} t^k i^{k} , $$
and taking the complex conjugate, $ \overline{i^k} = (-i)^{k} $ (you can check this for all four distinct powers of $i$ if you don't believe it, or use induction), and the result now follows since
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} s^{n-k} t^k (-i)^{k} = (s-it)^k . $$

Comment: I wish I could mark more answers with the green tick, because this one explains a lot from a different point of view! Thank you!